How to use pyyaml to create/modify conjur policy yaml files
I am working with conjur yaml policies formatted like this:
- !policy
  id: parent-id
  body:
    - !policy
      id: child1
      body:
        - &child1-variables
          - !variable var1
          - !variable var2

    - !policy
      id: child2
      body:
        - &child2-variables
          - !variable var1
          - !variable var2
    # Read access
    - !layer read-access
    - !permit
      role: !layer read-access
      privileges: [execute]
      resources: *child1-variables
    - !permit
      role: !layer read-access
      privileges: [execute]
      resources: *child2-variables

Per conjur-policy documentation, the yaml doc uses a special "!policy" tag along with mappings and collections.
I'd like to use python's pyyaml in order to:

read in the conjur config yaml file
add new !variable items to any &childX-variables collection if the collection exists. if collection does not exists, create it and add !variable to it

if new collection is written, I must also add a corresponding !permit node


write modified file back to system while maintaining structure

So far, in reading through pyyaml docs and a little help from copilot,
I can generally understand the need for custom representers and dumpers.  But I'm not sure how to move forward with reading in the file, modifying corresponding python objects, and writing file back to system.
Do you have any suggestions on how I can move forward ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is some sample code I've been working with.
As you can see, there are some undesired things in output:

double dashes
single quotes around !variable and anchors

Also, not sure how to read in the file into desired python objects
import yaml

class Permit(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!permit'
    def __init__(self, anchor):
        self.anchor = anchor
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}, {self.anchor}"

# Define a custom representer for the Variable class
def permit_representer(dumper, data):
    permit_dict = {
        'role': '!layer read-access',
        'privileges': '[execute]',
        'resources': '*' + data.anchor
    }
    return dumper.represent_mapping(data.yaml_tag, permit_dict)

# Add the custom representers to the YAML dumper
yaml.add_representer(Permit, permit_representer)



class Variable(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!variable'
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}, {self.name}"

# Define a custom representer for the Variable class
def variable_representer(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar(data.yaml_tag, data.name, style='')

# Add the custom representers to the YAML dumper
yaml.add_representer(Variable, variable_representer)

class Policy(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!policy'

class ParentPolicy(Policy):
    def __init__(self, id=None, child_list=[]):
        self.id = id
        self.child_list = child_list
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}, {self.id}, {self.child_list}"

# Define a custom representer for the ParentPolicy class
def parent_policy_representer(dumper, data):
    permit_anchors = [policy.anchor for policy in data.child_list]
    permit_nodes = [Permit(anchor) for anchor in permit_anchors]
    policy_dict = {
        'id': data.id,
        'body': [
            data.child_list,
            permit_nodes
        ]
    }
    return dumper.represent_mapping(data.yaml_tag, policy_dict)

# Add the custom representers to the YAML dumper
yaml.add_representer(ParentPolicy, parent_policy_representer)

class ChildPolicy(Policy):
    def __init__(self, id=None, anchor=None, variable_list=[]):
        self.id = id
        self.anchor = anchor
        self.variable_list = variable_list
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}, {self.id}, {self.anchor}, {self.variable_list}"


# Define a custom representer for the ChildPolicy class
def child_policy_representer(dumper, data):
    policy_dict = {
    'id': data.id,
    'body': [
        "&" + data.anchor,
        data.variable_list
    ]
    }
    return dumper.represent_mapping(data.yaml_tag, policy_dict)

# Add the custom representers to the YAML dumper
yaml.add_representer(ChildPolicy, child_policy_representer)

# Create a Policy instance
var1 = Variable("string1")
var2 = Variable("string2")
var3 = Variable("string3")
var4 = Variable("string4")
child_policy1 = ChildPolicy("child1", "child_anchor1", variable_list=[var1, var2])
child_policy2 = ChildPolicy("child2", "child_anchor2", variable_list=[var3, var4])
parent_policy = ParentPolicy("parent", child_list=[child_policy1, child_policy2])

# Print the formatted YAML output
print(yaml.dump([parent_policy], default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False))

with open("temp.yaml", "r") as f:
     loaded_yaml = yaml.full_load(f)

### print output:
- !policy
  id: parent
  body:
  - - !policy
      id: child1
      body:
      - '&child_anchor1'
      - - !variable 'string1'
        - !variable 'string2'
    - !policy
      id: child2
      body:
      - '&child_anchor2'
      - - !variable 'string3'
        - !variable 'string4'
  - - !permit
      role: '!layer read-access'
      privileges: '[execute]'
      resources: '*child_anchor1'
    - !permit
      role: '!layer read-access'
      privileges: '[execute]'
      resources: '*child_anchor2'

### yaml.full_load output
ConstructorError: expected a mapping node, but found scalar
  in "temp.yaml", line 6, column 11

